# SEO effect with different font for some characters?

Tags: seo, html, search-engines

I have a different font for some characters in my website, so the code is like this:

```
<h1>L<span style="letter-spacing: -5px">a </span><span 
      class="bletter">C</span>harte qualité mes <span     
      class="bletter">R</span>ideaux</h1>
```

It's good looking on my website, but words are cut by the HTML tags, is this a problem for SEO?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no hard evidence on this. Although it is conceivable that search engines and other programs treat `span` (and other inline elements) as breaking words, such behavior a) has no grounds in HTML specifications, b) has not been demonstrably detected, c) would break a large part of pages in identifying words, since such markup is common and the only way in general to style letters of a word differently (except in the sense that you could add the elements in client-side JavaScript).

However, in this case, it is possible to avoid the use of single-character markup. You might consider doing so for clarity (which affects maintainability), but you would also avoid the potential SEO risk mentioned. Example:

```
<style>
.special:first-letter { color: red;  }
.special { display: inline-block; }
</style>     
<h1><span style="word-spacing: -10px">La </span><span 
class="special">Charte</span> qualité mes <span     
class="special">Rideaux</span></h1>
```

So instead of styling specific letters (here styled red, for definiteness) wrapped in `span`, this would style the first letters of some words, so that `span` contains an entire word, not a letter. Since `span` by default is an inline element and `:first-letter` would not apply to it, I have set it to an inline block. Similarly, to remove spacing between words, this code sets negative word spacing, instead of character spacing. Note that in the original code, the `span` actually contains two characters, a letter and a space, and to get the same amount of spacing with `word-spacing`, I use a value twice as large.

Answer (score 0):

I can't tell for sure but I don't think it's great for SEO as your HTML is only used for style, not for meaning. Google might be smart enough to figure out there are words but I personally would avoid adding `span`s around letters on sites where I care about SEO.

Instead you should use [`::first-letter` and `::nth-letter()`](http://css-tricks.com/a-call-for-nth-everything/) to avoid putting HTML tags around specific letters.